# Batch file to remove files by extension except double extension?

Tags: file, batch-file

How can I remove files by extension except double extension?
Sorry for my English. Here's an example:

```
C:\test\song.mp3
C:\test\song.ogg
C:\test\song.ogg.asset
```

End Result I need after removeing files:

```
C:\test\song.ogg.asset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple to do if you jump over to Windows cmd. The lines below will remove all files with the extension .mp3 and .ogg while maintaining .ogg.asset.

(The * is a wildcard and will match any string before .mp3 / .ogg. The same is true of Bash).

```
del *.mp3
del *.ogg
```

You could use the above lines in a batch file and just run in the dir where you want to remove files. Of course there is likely more exciting ways of doing this...

Comment: That can be simplified to a single command: `del *.mp3 *.ogg`